# Populating a React component with data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to populate a React component using data available in Firestore.
I can get a console.log of the data without any problems, however, the dynamic element population doesn't happen, either by calling the Promise directly or through useEffect.

The only time I have it worked is when I add an onclick event on the  element and taking it away after the first click.

```
const OptionList = () => {

    const [list, setList] = useState({})
      
    const fetchData = () => {
        let data = []; 
        const response = getDocs(collection(db, 'listing'));

        response.then((results) => {
            let id = 1;
            results.forEach(function(doc) {
                const tempData = {id:id, name: doc.id, active: doc.data().active}
                id+=1;
                data.push(tempData);
            });
        })
        setList(data)
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //   fetchData()
    // }, []);  



    return(
        <>
            <select name="collection" id="collection" className="w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 placeholder-zinc-500" >
                <option value="new">New Collection</option>
                {Object.values(list).map((item) => <option key={item.id} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option> )} 
                {Object.values(list).forEach((item) => console.log(item) )} 
            </select>
        </>
    )
}
```

Any indication of where to issues lie is very much appreciated.

Comment: `list` is initially an empty object `{}` but then you change it's type to an array `[]`

Comment: That's what I thought. But every time I got an object back. That's why I have used  `Object.values(list)` to iterate over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the call to setList inside the promise callback. Right now it's always setting an empty list before the database results are hanlded, because promise callbacks are always asynchronous.

```
        response.then((results) => {
            let id = 1;
            results.forEach(function(doc) {
                const tempData = {id:id, name: doc.id, active: doc.data().active}
                id+=1;
                data.push(tempData);
            });
            setList(data)
        })
```

If you add more logging in and around the callback you'll be able to better see the order in which everything executes.

Comment: Thanks Doug! That was indeed the issue.